# Save image to gallery

Tags: android, save, gallery

I'm try to save a Image in the externalStorage, but, there are mobiles that it works in some mobiles, but en others not.

I think that it's because the API level, but I tried to change it but it don't works me.

The image are saved in the directory of the app, but I can't introduce at the gallery, I don't know if I have to do differents cases, or it's possible to do it with the same code.

The problem is that in mobiles like news Motorola, or mobiles with Kitkat, more or less at the same time, don't save at the gallery. I have readed a lot of code, but I tried with Mediastore, Mediascannerconnection, intents...

I would like to put the image at the gallery, if you can resolve my doubt, I  would be very grateful.

Here's is the command that works on my smartphone, with 4.0, but not in kitkat:

`MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),pathfile,namefile,namefile);`

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

try calling [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html) after `.insertImage`

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { filePhoto.getPath() }, new String[] { "image/jpeg" }, null);
```